# Why does `exams` prints the figure legend when plotting `ggplot2` plots?

Tags: r, r-markdown, r-exams

When I use `exams2nops()` or `exams2moodle()`

```
Question
========
Some questions...
```

```r
pacman::p_load(ggplot2, magrittr)
#make sample data
groups <- letters[23:26]

df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(n = 60,mean = 3.5, sd = 3.4),
                 y = rnorm(n = 60,mean = 3.5, sd = 3.4),
                 g = c(rep(groups[1],15),rep(groups[2],15),rep(groups[3],15),rep(groups[4],15)))


colors_pal <- c("#264653", "#2a9d8f", "#457b9d", "#e76f51")

plot_reg_line_equation <- function(df, groups, colors_pal) {
    ggplot(data = dplyr::filter(.data = df, g==groups), aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE, color="black", formula = y ~ x) +
    geom_point() + 
    ggtitle(label = paste0(groups)) +
    jtools::theme_apa() +
    theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
          panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          panel.border = element_blank(),
          panel.background = element_blank())
  }

lapply(groups, plot_reg_line_equation, df = df) %>% patchwork::wrap_plots()
solution <- groups==groups[1]
```

```r
exams::answerlist(groups, markup = "markdown")
```

```
Solution
========
Some solution feedback.


Meta-information
================
exname: example
extype: schoice
exsolution: `r paste(solution)`
exshuffle: 4
```

I end up with two strange things, first the legend. And second the answer options.

[image]

Note: I noticed that if I had some kind of text immediatly aftwer the plot chunk it does not produced the legend (e.g. even if it is html `<br>`) however, I would like to understand this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set `fig.cap = ""` in the options for the R code chunk that generates the figure. As usual in R/Markdown this suppresses the caption of the figure.

*Further notes:*

- You haven't shown the options that you use currently.
- In the `exsolution` you need `mchoice2string()` instead of `paste()`.

Comment: Do you know why this happens? Why it does not appear if I add `<br>`?

Comment: The caption is included by default only if the figure code chunk is in its own paragraph, i.e., with a blank line preceeding it. You can avoid the blank line by including a `<br>` tag but this only works for HTML output. Another option that works for both HTML and PDF output is to include a line with only a backslash `\`. This is what is done in several of the R/exams templates, e.g., http://www.R-exams.org/templates/boxplots/

Comment: Good, know I can better understand the behavior when printing plots.